# text column convert to date for visual studio graph

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am writing a clickonce application in vb.net. I have sql tables linked to a Microsoft Access database, and then my application reads through the OLEDB connection.

My columns in SQL are saved as date however when linked to MS Access they convert to "text" I haven't had any issues with this until I started creating charts on my application. I need the dates on the chart to display as jan 17 feb 17 etc however no matter what formatting I use they come back as '2017-01-01' '2017-02-01'

I have tried

```
     ChartFCR.Series(0).XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime
     ChartFCR.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMMyy"
```

in various forms and nothing is changing the appearance. any information or suggestion is helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way Access will make sense of a SQL date data type is if it is converted into 1) a datetime in SQL or 2) a date in Access.

Of course it depends on your situation, but try creating a query in Access that handles that conversion and base the chart on the query. That would give you the most control for the Access interface.